# Является ли wpdb->replace защищенным от sql инъекций?

Tags: wordpress

Почитал статью https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb, очень познавательная.

Вот только я не понял одну вещь. Функции insert, update, replace, delete которые находятся в классе wpdb защищены ли от SQL инъекций?

я понял, что надо использовать prepare, но в примерах я увидел только вариант с собственным запросом, произвольным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Имейте ввиду, что как и для всех функций класса wpdb, передаваемые
>   параметры нужно очистить от SQL инъекций, сделать это можно двумя
>   способами:
>
> 1) esc_sql( $user_entered_data_string ). 2) $wpdb->prepare(  'query' ,
>   value_parameter[, value_parameter ... ] ).
>
> $wpdb->insert() включает защиту от SQL инъекций и данные можно
>   передавать как есть, например: $_GET['foo']...
>
> ВНИМАНИЕ! Вернет false (без каких либо ошибок), когда передаваемая для
>   вставки строка (значение ячейки) длинее максимально возможного.
>   Например колонка varchar(10) (длина значения 10 символов), а в
>   переданных данных для вставки указана строка с 11 или более символами.
>
> Поймать такой баг очень сложно! Поэтому надо иметь это ввиду, когда
>   все вроде бы должно работать (правильные данные передается), но
>   wpdb::insert() возвращает false без каких-либо ошибок.
>
> Такая проблема касается почти всех методов, это: wpdb::replace()
>   wpdb::insert() wpdb::update() wpdb::delete()

То есть четыре метода с защитой, остальные самостоятельно, предоставленными методами